# how to delete single photo in gallery with Laravel

Tags: laravel, delete-file

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
       $delete = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
       $storegallery = json_decode($delete -> gallery);
       foreach($storegallery as $file){
        unlink('storege/gallery/'.$file);
        $delete -> delete();  
          return back();
       }

       
    }
```

unlink(storege/gallery/192242c2feb319b20192c61a16ed8da0.png): No such file or directory

Comment: while clicking delete then you need to pass image name also .so that you can delete particular file.better if you add blade template code also

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, there is a typo in the word ´storege´. The simlink is ´storage´.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in this line:

```
unlink('storege/gallery/'.$file); // 'storege' should be 'storage'
```

Try this:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
       $delete = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
       $storegallery = json_decode($delete -> gallery);
       foreach($storegallery as $file){
           if($file && file_exists("storage/gallery/".$file) && is_file("storage/gallery/".$file))
           {
               unlink('storage/gallery/'.$file);
               $delete -> delete(); 
           }
           else{echo $file.' - File Not found in storage/gallery'} 
           return back();
       }

       
    }
```